# React Native on Android, Deep linking and Linking library.

Tags: android, reactjs, native

What I am trying to achieve is the following:
1. Get the referrer details when the app was installed.
2. Do I get the details of the referer if the user never opened the app?

This is what I want to do with the app:

1. Put the APK on mydomain.com. When I buying traffic to send to the app I will send it to mydomain.com?referrer=123.
2. Add the APK to Google Play.

When users will (hopefully) install the app, I would like to know more about how they go there. i.e. Referrer. 
In Google Play it is INSTALL_REFERRER (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-implement) and on mydomain.com I suppose it will be utilising it like so: http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html#adding-filters.

FB on the other hand said that intentAndroid is deprecated and to use Linking instead.

How do I go about that?

Thank you!

Comment: Any insights on that?